# AZCOPY downloading images asks for override

Tags: azure, cloud, blob, azcopy

When I start copying all images from the container into an empty folder it asks if I wish to overwrite the file. Why this is happening? I have got /s argument specified to do recursive download. As I see it downloads into the right directory structure. File must be unique so this question should not be asked.
I use next command

AzCopy /Dest:C:\images /Source:https://*.blob.core.windows.net/images/ /SourceKey:a_key /s

Is it a bug or I do something wrong?

Comment: Nice surprise with string IDs and that cloud url is case sensitive and windows is ignoring case.
Is there an option to reconfigure windows to be case sensitive?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue and there isn't anything to fix from AzCopy's side. Names of Windows file system is case insensitive, which is by design and can't be configured. To work around this issue, please rename one of your blob to avoid distinguishing blobs only by capitalization.

Comment: I was naive and tried to configure W2K8 R2. I found an article on tech support but it simply doesn't work.